# How to choose open mode with fopen()?

Tags: c, linux, file-io, fopen

I have a problem about file open mode with `fopen()`.

In my case, I want to seek the cursor freely, may be even beyond `EOF` sometimes. What's more, I also want to append to it instead of truncating the existing file. I tried to open the file in `a+` mode; however, I cannot seek file cursor freely. Each time I seek the cursor beyond `EOF`, new arrival data will be append to end of the file, not the position I specified. While, if open in `w+` mode, the existing file will be truncated. Is there a perfect solution to this problem?

---

UPDATE:

One point not clearly specified is that the file may not always exist; I have to create a new file in that case.

In fact, I want to process a configuration file. I don't know whether it is good practice to implement like this. Or should I first place an empty configuration file. Thus there is no need to care about the case file does not exist?

Below is the code snippet:

```
FILE *f = fopen(FILE_PATH, "wb+");
struct record r;
if (f) {
    if (fread((void *)&r, 1, sizeof(struct record), f) {
        /* File exists, do the normal flow */
    } else {
        if (feof(f)) {
            /* File is newly created, do some initialization */
        }
    }
} else {
    /* issue a warning */
}
```

Comment: Can you post the relevant code here?

Comment: I'm curious.. why are you looking to seek/write beyond EOF?

Comment: @OrionRogue I use a file to emulate hard disk. Data is read and write in chunks. So initially the file is empty, data may fall behind `EOF`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will have to deal with the possibly non-existent file in two stages, first assuming that it is there and then dealing with its absence:

```
if ((f = fopen(filename, "rb+") == 0)
    f = fopen(filename, "wb+");
if (f == 0)
    ...report error...
```

The `"rb+"` mode will fail to open a non-existent file (but otherwise behaves as you want).  If the file doesn't exist, then `"wb+"` will do what you want instead (though it could still fail, for example if the file exists but you don't have permission to write to it). You have to hope that you've not been subjected to a TOCTOU (Time of Check, Time of Use) attack with the double attempt.

An alternative approach uses the 3-argument version of the `open()` system call with appropriate flags to open a file descriptor, and then uses `fdopen()` to create a file stream from the file descriptor:

```
#include <fcntl.h>

int fd;
if ((fd = open(filename, O_RDRW | O_CREAT, 0644)) >= 0)
    f = fdopen(fd, "rb+");
```

You get rather precise control over [`open()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/open.html) with the flags.

Comment: Normally you can pass `0666` as the permission bits and trust the user to set the umask.  This also means that the user *can* set the umask, instead of having to `chmod` the files manually afterwards.

Comment: The `fdopen` approach is the only safe one.

Comment: @DietrichEpp That's a valid observation - if you trust your users to know what a `umask` is.  I work in security; I don't trust my users.  We don't have a bigger context.  I note that if the file exists, its permissions will be unchanged, so if the user wants anyone and everyone to edit their configuration, they can set the public and group write permissions.  I don't regard allowing other people (any other people) to modify my configuration as secure, hence the deliberate (but uncommented upon) use of 0644 instead of 0666.

Comment: @R..: It (`open()` plus `fdopen()`) would be the mechanism I'd use, but file descriptors are fair play in the contexts where I work.  If the local standard is to use file streams only, then the double attempt is the nearest approximation to correct, TOCTOU problems and all.

Comment: Here's a safer variant: use `fopen` with `"ab+"` to create the file in the case where it doesn't exist, then close and retry from the beginning.

Comment: @R..: How is that safer than `"rb+"` and `"wb+"` if that fails?

Comment: Using `0666` will match the behavior of `fopen`, which uses `0666` (at least glibc does).  If your `umask` is wrong, you have bigger problems anyway.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: In the case where `"rb+"` failed by the file was created by somebody else immediately after, the subsequent `"wb+"` will truncate the file. Using `"ab+"` instead to create the file will avoid truncation, and on the next round, the `"rb+"` will get the now-existing file.

Answer (score 2):

The file modes are clearly documented for `fopen` (try `man 3 fopen` on Unix/Linux/OS X).

> `r+`  Open for reading and writing.  The stream is positioned at the beginning of the file.

Comment: The `"rb+"` or `"r+"` mode fails when the file does not exist; in that case, you have to go back and try again with `"wb+"` or `"w+"`, hoping that you've not been subjected to a TOCTOU (Time of Check, Time of Use) attack.

Comment: If you want "modify if exists; otherwise, create empty" semantics on POSIX, `fopen` is not useful. You'll need `open` followed by `fdopen`.

Answer (score -1):

Hi， you can use "w+" to read and write by fseek, i wrote a little demo program, write data to file first and use fseek to make each data intervals some byte, and then read it:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define FILE_PATH "seek_test.txt"
#define STEP_SIZE 64

void set_data(FILE* fp)
{
    int i = 0;
    fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET);

    for ( ; i < 20; ++i)
    {
        fprintf(fp, "%d", i);
        fseek(fp, STEP_SIZE, SEEK_CUR);
    }
}

void get_data(FILE* fp)
{
    int i = 0;
    fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET);

    for ( ; i < 20; ++i)
    {
        fscanf(fp, "%d", &i);
        fprintf(stderr, "Cur Step: %5ld, value = %4d\n", i * STEP_SIZE, i);
        fseek(fp, STEP_SIZE, SEEK_CUR);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    FILE* fp = fopen(FILE_PATH, "w+");
    if (fp == NULL)
    {
        printf("fopen Error\n");
        exit(0);
    }

    set_data(fp);
    get_data(fp);

    return 0;
}
```

===============================
result as follows:

Cur Step:     0, value =    0

Cur Step:    64, value =    1

Cur Step:   128, value =    2

Cur Step:   192, value =    3

Cur Step:   256, value =    4

Cur Step:   320, value =    5

Cur Step:   384, value =    6

Cur Step:   448, value =    7

Cur Step:   512, value =    8

Cur Step:   576, value =    9

Cur Step:   640, value =   10

Cur Step:   704, value =   11

Cur Step:   768, value =   12

Cur Step:   832, value =   13

Cur Step:   896, value =   14

Cur Step:   960, value =   15

Cur Step:  1024, value =   16

Cur Step:  1088, value =   17

Cur Step:  1152, value =   18

Cur Step:  1216, value =   19

=============================

Comment: Thanks, still cannot satisfy all the requirements. I finally take Jonathan's answer.

Comment: This will truncate the file.