# How to Create database using structures in C

Tags: c, struct, fopen, fread

I am trying to create binary database writing program in **C**.

**Problem** is that when database is updated the Program deletes previous data of file and stores new updated data only.

**Program :**

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main (){

    struct STUINFO { char  fname[30], lname[30], year[5], batchno[30];};
    int id, s, roll;
    FILE *outfile;

    // open file for writing

    if (outfile = fopen ("stuinfo.bin", "w") == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "\nError opening file\n");
        return (-1);
    }
    printf("\nEnter Nine Digit Enrollment no. :\n");
    scanf("%d", &roll);
    id = roll - 100000000;
    if (id < 0 ) { 
        printf("Please Enter Valid Nine Digit no.\n");
        return -2;
        }

    struct STUINFO output;
    printf("Enter First Name :\n");
    scanf("%s", output.fname);
    printf("Enter Last Name :\n");
    scanf("%s", output.lname);
    printf("Enter Year of Semester :\n");
    scanf("%s", output.year);
    printf("Enter Batch no. :\n");
    scanf("%s", output.batchno);

    s = sizeof(struct STUINFO);
    fseek(outfile, +id*s, SEEK_CUR);
    // write struct to file

    if(fwrite (&output, sizeof(struct STUINFO), 1, outfile) != 0) 
        printf("contents to file written successfully !\n");
    else 
        printf("error writing file !\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `include stdio.h` is a syntax error.

Comment: Open mode `w` erases the file. If you want to append to a file, use `a`.

Comment: BTW `fwrite != 0` is nonsense

Comment: Please study and apply the concept of a [mcve].

Comment: Please post real code, the code you posted doesn't compile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file is truncated when you use:

```
fopen ("stuinfo.bin", "w");
```

To open the file for writing without truncating, use:

```
fopen ("stuinfo.bin", "r+");
```

But this won't create the file if it doesn't exist, so you have to check for an error and then open in `w` mode if it fails.

```
if ((outfile = fopen("stuinfo.bin", "r+") == 0) {
    outfile = fopen("stuinfo.bin", "w");
}
```

See [How to choose open mode with fopen()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10573984/how-to-choose-open-mode-with-fopen)

Also, since you're writing a binary file, you should use the `b` modifier:

```
fopen ("stuinfo.bin", "rb+");
```

It doesn't make a difference on Unix, but does on other operating systems, so it's necessary for portability.

Comment: r+ worked for it.but if file is not there then it shows error.i think it should creat new file instead.

Comment: I've updated the answer to show how to deal with that.